# jquery if more than 4 images add tag to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

so I am really bad with jquery and I need help with a code. So I am doing carousel and there are going to be 4 images and I want it to be static (disable carousel, remove html tag or smth.) but if resolution is >1000px enable carousel. But if there are 5 image just enable it.

Sorry for bad English, thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example to show what have you completed? Or at least put the simplified code to here, so we are able to know where's the problem.

Comment: I am not doing whole carousel just this responsive kind a thingy. I haven't started doing it yet but I have no Idea how to do it. I know I can do something with jquery .length but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

the attr() from jquery should allow you to test for the size of >= and do what you are trying to do.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume you the image's count is fixed when the page is completely loaded. And the images you want to put in carousel, has class `carousel`, you can write something like this.

```
// jQuery onDomready
$(function(){
  var CAROUSEL_THRESHOLD = 1000;
  var IMAGECOUNT_THRESHOLD = 4;
  // Get window width;
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  var images = $('.carousel');
  var imageCount = images.length;

  if (screenWidth >= CAROUSEL_THRESHOLD || imageCount > IMAGECOUNT_THRESHOLD) {
    // Enable the carousel. ....
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, so I managed to make responsive side. But I now have 2 jquery files and now for example if there are 5 image use this jquery file if 4 use this one how to do that?

Comment: `2 jquery files` means? 2 independent group of images? Your example is saying that: You have 2 groups of images, and you want to apply this independently to those 2 groups, so 1. The group with 5 image will carousel and 2. The group with 4 image will stay static?

Comment: No I am using 2 jquery files for settings not for images and stuff. I am using owl-carousel and it has settings there you can turn off whole carousel or add some settings so... :)

Comment: So you want this code to accept a given setting? So the `CAROUSEL_THRESHOLD` and `IMAGECOUNT_THRESHOLD ` things can be decide by you?